# How to count page hit in oracle form d2k application

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How do I count page hit or no of visitor in oracle form d2k application?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option:

- create a table, e.g.

  ```
  create table hits (form_name varchar2(30), hits number);
  ```
- create a stored procedure which will be used to maintain that table. It'll be an autonomous transaction procedure (so that you could `commit` without affecting the main transaction), and it'll lock the `hits` table (will it affect execution in multi-user environment? Shouldn't have, it is really *fast*).

  ```
  create or replace procedure p_hits (par_form_name in varchar2) 
  is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
    lock table hits in exclusive mode;

    merge into hits h
      using (select par_form_name form_name from dual) x
      on (x.form_name = h.form_name)
      when matched then 
        update set h.hits = h.hits + 1
      when not matched then 
        insert (form_name, hits) values (par_form_name, 1);

      commit;
  end p_hits;
  /
  ```
- call that procedure in form's `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` form-level trigger:

  ```
  p_hits(:system.current_form);
  ```

That would be all; query the `hits` table to see its contents.